# How can I rewrite build.gradle files when I use Android Studio Chipmunk?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I create an project based the wizard *Empty Compose Activity* of Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1, and the wizard generate two build.gradle files, you can see Code A and Code B.

Code C and Code D are two build.gradle files from an old project.

1:  What does `apply false` in `id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false` of Code A mean?

2: I find that the *plugins* section exist both Code A and Code B which have almost the same code, why?

3: I find there is a *dependencies* section in Code C, is it obsolete ?

4:  Is *repositories* section in Code C obsolete ?

**Code A: Sample build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}
```

**Code B: Sample build.gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.dodata.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    ...
}
```

**Code C: My build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0'
        hilt_version = '2.42'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}
```

**Code D:  build.gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    flavorDimensions "default"
    namespace 'info.dodata.soundmeter'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.dodata.soundmeter"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.03"

        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        allWarningsAsErrors = false
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    ...
```

Comment: with Android Chipmunk, you should take a look in settings.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio Chipmunk creates a different structure for Gradle files, with a `settings.gradle` for repositories and a `build.gradle` (project level) for plugins. In short, this new structure just makes the `Gradle files` cleaner.
With `Gradle` is common to see 2 (or more) ways to do the same thing. Comparing `code A` with `code C` is the perfect example. Both codes do the same thing but with a different structure in code and file.

Now talking about `apply false`, it's basically literally. You declare a plugin, with a version, and say to not apply it immediately (in entire project, since it's a build.gradle from project). But you apply what you need only in the module that you are going to use this plugin, for example, in the `build.gradle` from `app module`.
You can take a look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl) for a complete description.

Back to the "new structure" generated by Android Studio with plugins, sometimes you will need to create a `dependencies` block inside `buildscript` to use the "old" `classpath` instead a `plugin id` because currently not all libraries have the plugin to be used.